# Collecting pytest results in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pytest

I would like to parse and collect pytest results in pandas dataframe.
Is there any way to parse it ?

I only found this reference, which am not sure how to use it.
[Collecting and Reporting pytest Results](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29597972/collecting-and-reporting-pytest-results)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could implement a custom `makereport` hook in your `conftest.py`. A simple example:

```
import pytest
import pandas as pd


df = pd.DataFrame(columns=('failed', 'nodeid', ))


@pytest.hookimpl(tryfirst=True, hookwrapper=True)
def pytest_runtest_makereport(item, call):
    global df
    outcome = yield
    rep = outcome.get_result()

    if rep.when == 'call':
        df = df.append({'failed': rep.failed, 'nodeid': rep.nodeid}, ignore_index=True)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`pytest-harvest`](https://smarie.github.io/python-pytest-harvest/) for this. Simply install it, and you can directly use the pre-defined fixtures:

```
import pytest
import time

@pytest.mark.parametrize('p', ['world', 'self'], ids=str)
def test_foo(p):
    """
    A dummy test, parametrized so that it is executed twice
    """
    print('\n   hello, ' + p + ' !')
    time.sleep(len(p) / 10)

def test_synthesis(module_results_df):
    """
    Shows that the `module_results_df` fixture already contains what you need
    """
    # drop the 'pytest_obj' column
    module_results_df.drop('pytest_obj', axis=1, inplace=True)

    print("\n   `module_results_df` dataframe:\n")
    print(module_results_df)
```

Yields

```
>>> pytest -s -v

============================= test session starts =============================
...
collecting ... collected 3 items
test_basic.py::test_foo[world] 
   hello, world !
PASSED
test_basic.py::test_foo[self] 
   hello, self !
PASSED
test_basic.py::test_synthesis 
   `module_results_df` dataframe:

                 status  duration_ms      p
test_id                                    
test_foo[world]  passed   500.028610  world
test_foo[self]   passed   400.022745   self
PASSED

========================== 3 passed in 0.05 seconds ===========================
```

You can also start from the 'dict' fixture, which contains more details about setup/teardown times, and convert it to a dataframe using the provided helper methods.
See documentation for details.

Finally, if you wish to also use parameters, fixtures, steps... you might wish to look at this [datascience benchmark example](https://smarie.github.io/pytest-patterns/examples/data_science_benchmark/)

I'm the author by the way ;)